# Java UTF-8 string serialization \xF2 instead of \u00F2

Tags: java, utf-8

I have a string with UTF8 characters in it and I'm using StringEntity to put it into a HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase and send it to a server.
My problem is that the UTF8 characters are coded as \xF2 and the server would like \u00f2. How can I fix this? Or how can I easily convert an UTF-8 string to a string where I have \u00f2 like substrings instead of the UTF8 chars?

Solution:
In the end, the solution was:
    StringEntity(string, "UTF-8"));

Thanks in advance, David

Comment: Q: where's the "8" in (16-bit) "\u00f2"???

Comment: Ok, so my main question should be how can I convert UTF-8 to UTF-16?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert between Java's internal character encoding (UTF-16) and UTF-8 byte sequences in a variety of ways. The simplest is:

```
byte[] utf8data = "my string".getBytes("UTF-8");
String myString = new String(utf8data, "UTF-8");
```

There are also stream-oriented classes that can translate between byte streams and character streams using an encoding. See the `java.io` package.